# Why data values change as I create a ts object?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm having a hard time creating a time series object in R. I have a csv which I import into a variable, then, after I create the time series, the data values have all changed and I really dont understand why. Here's what Im doing:

```
var1<-read.csv("C:\\user\\file.csv",header=T)
serie1<-ts(var1,frequency=52,starts=c(2013,5),ends=c(2015,4))
```

But if you call the timeserie

```
serie1
```

All values have changed into random data, why is this happening?

Comment: Please provide a structure or sample data for the contents of var1.

Comment: And please be aware that options in `ts` are `start` and `end`, without final "s". Are you working with weekly values?

Comment: Yes, I am working with weekly values. Sorry about the final "s", The structure of var1 data would be something like this: 
Week Sales
201305 4104.4
201306 3211.5
201307 3023.6 

And so on, I have a total of 104 observations. (I just cant get this to be shown in columns but data is arranged in two columns)